# Postgres expand time window using date_part

Tags: postgresql

Have two dates - '2018-05-01' and '2018-06-01'. I would like to expand this window to the past by day difference of those dates.

```
 SELECT * FROM data
 WHERE 
 start_time > CAST('2018-05-01' AS timestamptz) - INTERVAL '30 DAY'   
 AND start_time < CAST('2018-06-01' AS timestamptz)
```

How can I replace INTERVAL '30 DAY' with number of days between given dates without explicitly defining number of days? I know to calculate day difference:

```
date_part('day',age('2018-05-01', '2018-06-01'))
```

But not sure how to incorporate into the substraction. Dates and days between them will change.

Comment: So `2018-05-01 - 2018-06-01` should "become" `2018-03-31 - 2018-06-01`? or should the result be `2018-03-31 - 2018-05-01`

Comment: 2018-03-31 - 2018-06-01 should be date range to filter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_trunc('mon', some_date_expression)` to *round down* to the start of a month:

---

```
select date_trunc('mon', now() - '3 mon'::interval) as date_begin
        , date_trunc('mon', now() - '1 day'::interval) as date_end
        ;
```

---

Result

---

```
       date_begin       |        date_end        
------------------------+------------------------
 2018-03-01 00:00:00+01 | 2018-06-01 00:00:00+02
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply subtract the difference from the start date:

```
with t (start_date, end_date) as (
  values (date '2018-05-01', date '2018-06-01')
)
select start_date - (end_date - start_date) as new_start, 
       end_date
from t;
```

returns

```
new_start  | new_end   
-----------+-----------
2018-03-31 | 2018-06-01
```